# my ubuntu20.04 Black screen after login

Tags: login-screen

I tried to remove the last app(fcitx) and reboot, but it didn't work. I find on the internet, reinstall the ubuntu-desktop or the lightdm, the graphical interface just can't display correct, but I can see my cursor and a black screen, ctrl+alt+f2 can open the tty. i can't find the Xauthority file or xsession-error file in my /home directory.so how can I enter the ubuntu graphical desktop,help~

Comment: why I can't find my .xsession-errors file in /home ?

Comment: I would suggest a fresh reinstall.

Comment: fine,i tried to reinstall again ,but screen keeps freezing.Orz

Comment: You booted from a live cd or usb and did a new install?

Comment: yes，from my usb.But the first time into the system interface is stuck.

Comment: The previous 18.04 does not work like this, is 20.04 different hardware requirements

Comment: All you needed to do is google it. Ubuntu Desktop Edition
Here's what Canonical lists as the recommended minimum system requirements for installing the desktop edition of Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa (source). Keep in mind that this pertains to physical installs. Virtualized installs can actually get by with less.

2 GHz dual core processor
4 GiB RAM (system memory)
25 GB of hard drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media